# How to convert C# Asp.Net IActionResult to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This method:

```
public IActionResult Index(string CatId)
```

might return

```
NotFound("Cat does not exist");
```

Or

```
this.Content(catname);
```

However, here's what actually is returned if the cat is found:

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ContentResult**

How do I get the string that I really want?

Comment: Where are you trying to access this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score -2):

```
public IActionResult Index(string CatId)
        {
          string catName=null;
            try
            {
           /*your code to get catname*/
                if (catName != null)
                {
                    return Ok(catName);
                }
                return NotFound();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return  InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Aldert what's wrong with this ? It's gonna return `catname` perfectly.

Comment: No it is not, catName is set to null. Then you check if catName is null (what never will be the case). It will always step to return NotFound()

Comment: buddy, I did not give you the minus on this answer. You edited the answer 2 hours ago.

Comment: @Aldert edit was `NotFound("Cat does not exist");` to `NotFound()`.